# Scala class value without an instance

Tags: scala, class

For interoperability with a Java library, I need to get an instance of the `java.lang.Class[T]`. Suppose that I've got the following `case class` definition:

```
case class Foo(name: String, colour: String, amount: Int)
```

Given an instance of `val bar: Foo` I can get the class of that instance by calling `bar.getClass`.

However, I don't have an instance of `Foo` yet: that's why I need an instance of `Class[T]`. Is there anyway of getting such an instance of `Class[T]` without creating an instance of `Foo`?

Comment: D'oh! I should have known.... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways of getting a class value in Scala, using the predefined function [`classOf`](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/109).

In your case (as noted by @Kolmar), `classOf[Foo]` can be used to get the class of an uninstantiated object. Note that the output of this can be a bit confusing (from a worksheet):

```
classOf[Foo] = class A$A12$A$A12$Foo
classOf[String]  // class java.lang.String
classOf[List[String]]  // class scala.collection.immutable.List
classOf[Array[String]]  // class [Ljava.lang.String;
```

That latter one can be easy to confuse, given the slightly strange output syntax.